# Refreshing tableview data after dismiss() called on another tableview

Tags: swift, xcode

Setup: table view controller has button (Add) that pops up another view controller with a form.  I'm using `Realm` to store data, so no need to pass data back.  However, when I `dismiss()` the view controller, and return to the table view controller, I cannot get `tableView.reloadData()` to work.

I have tried `viewWillAppear()` and `viewDidAppear()` but neither appear to be in the call stack.

Any ideas where I need to put this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a delegate

```
let second = ///
second.delegate = self
```

When  you dismiss in 2nd vc

```
delegate?.refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your second controller is being displayed modally. According to [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear):

> If a view controller is presented by a view controller inside of a popover, this method is not invoked on the presenting view controller after the presented controller is dismissed.

You can solve your problem with a delegate:

```
protocol ControllerBDelegate {
    func willDismiss()
}

class ControllerA {

    func open() {
        let vc = ControllerB()
        vc.delegate = self
        self.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

extension ControllerA : ControllerBDelegate {
    func willDismiss() {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

class ControllerB {
    weak var delegate: ControllerBDelegate?

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        delegate?.willDismiss()
    }
}
```